# Remnants of MATLAB Popup Selection Example Stay There

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am still learning my way around MATLAB's gui. I used one of GUIDE's templates, precisely the `GUI with Axes and Menu`.

This generates two files: GUIFigure.m and GUIFigure.fig

At first, I deleted the line that gives labels to the popup menu which goes along the following lines:

```
function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(hObject, 'String', {'old text 1', 'old text 2');
```

When I replaced the text inside the curly brackets with my own text, it worked fine. When I replaced it with a cell variable and used incorrect syntax, it would give me an error, which is understandable, but the figure would still pop up with the old text.

Another similar issue is that the example already has a plot with axes. Now I deleted the axes from the .fig file, and I also deleted their code in the .m file. However when I run the gui function, the axes still show up with the plot, although I've even deleted the code that generates the data for the plot!

Any explanation/tips as to what is going on would be appreciated.

```
function varargout = FIAFigure(varargin)
% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @FIAFigure_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @FIAFigure_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before FIAFigure is made visible.
function FIAFigure_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)


% Choose default command line output for FIAFigure
handles.output = hObject;

handles.dataSetsCell = varargin{1};
handles.categoryNames = varargin{2};

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

if strcmp(get(hObject,'Visible'),'off')
    plot(rand(5));
end



% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = FIAFigure_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
varargout{1} = handles.output;

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
t = uitable(handles.uitable1);

cla;

popup_sel_index = get(handles.popupmenu1, 'Value');
set(t,'Data',magic(popup_sel_index))



% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function FileMenu_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function OpenMenuItem_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
file = uigetfile('*.fig');
if ~isequal(file, 0)
    open(file);
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function PrintMenuItem_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
printdlg(handles.figure1)

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function CloseMenuItem_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
selection = questdlg(['Close ' get(handles.figure1,'Name') '?'],...
                     ['Close ' get(handles.figure1,'Name') '...'],...
                     'Yes','No','Yes');
if strcmp(selection,'No')
    return;
end

delete(handles.figure1)


% --- Executes on selection change in popupmenu1.
function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(hObject, 'String', {handles.categoryNames{1:end}});


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
     set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
    end


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function uitable1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

Comment: Did you hit save after modifying the .fig file? Did you close the figure between runs of the code?

Comment: There is also a possibility that your old text or *axes commands* still exist in some other parts of the code (the `opening function` for example). I suggest you to simplify your code as much as possible and give us a complete executable example of the problem your are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for the answers folks. I've provided the code above.
@wakjah indeed I did close the figure and saved the file between runs of code.

Comment: @pm89 you were right, there were some lines of code lying around for plotting etc that I hadnt spotted. I removed them now (there were many, you need to remove them all!) and now the plot no longer comes up.  Guess I was too tired to spot them yesterday, thanks a lot guys! Would be it be best to delete this question as it turns out to be a very particular case?